# mySQL 5.5 starting server/ privelages denied in snow leopard

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I just installed mysql 5.5.16 for snow leopard (via pkg install), but I have no permissions when running mysql (i.e. cannot grant privelages) and a lot of my commands are not recognized in shell/ bash (i.e. all of the 'mysql' commands are not recognized).

I think I'm logged in as root, but when I do 'select user()', it shows that I'm signed is as 'btran' (not sure if this was created on accident, i just want to access to root and i'm not sure how to do that). Everything is on my local machine, just wanted to start learning mysql.  I can provide more information, but any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify; what errors are you getting when you try the mysql commands? If the command can't be found then it's probably a path issue (A quick google search shows the mysql command is /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql in snow leopard but I don't have a mac myself).

Second--just so we're clear--being root in the OS is not being root in MySQL. If the binaries are installed in the afore mentioned location, set your root password with the...

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password [PASSWORD]
```

...command. Then login via...

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

EDIT: The path problem definitely seems right. Check out http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: THANKS FOR THIS!  To clarify on my problem, I was unable to log in as root in mySQL and was thus unable to grant any privelages or do any of the administration needed to set up my sample database.  I used your commands it works perfectly.  I unfortunately have been without the training book so I've been unable to test and confirm that I have everything I need, but it seems i should be fine or at least on the right track.  Thanks again for your help!